# Color UIImage like the color splurge app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

How to change the color of the UIImage using the finger touch of the user like in color splurge application? I was able to convert the image into grey scale but when user touches the image it should show its original colors . How to do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hi my suggestion u need to keep two images one is in background and another one in foreground(it is gray scaled image) and remove the touch parts of the image...

Comment: please see the video is this u need to achieve http://www.screencast.com/t/qlVUPdnSL

Comment: It applies color very perfectly and i know how to create a grey scale.but to which image view should i apply the grey scale and what should be the color while touching the image view?

Answer (score 0):

You can addGesture to your UIImage

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Or you can do it through touchesBegan and touchesEnde methods and detect if the touch is inside your imageRect

here's a small tutorial to go ahead with.

http://www.ioslearner.com/tag/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial/

I hope it helps you!
Cheers!!